# Semi-distinct union

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

There are `UNION` and `UNION ALL` operators in SQL. The first one drops all the duplicates, the second one doesn't. I want to drop only duplicates which originated in different subqueries, but keep those which come from the same one. Example:

```
TABLE t1:     TABLE t2:     TABLE t3:
a | b         a | b         a | b
—————         —————         —————
1 | 2         1 | 2         1 | 3
1 | 2                       1 | 3
```

I want `(SELECT * FROM t1) UNION SEMI (SELECT * FROM t3)` to return all four rows,
then `(SELECT * FROM t2) UNION SEMI (SELECT * FROM t2)` to return one row.
I don't really care what
`(SELECT * FROM t1) UNION SEMI (SELECT * FROM t2)` would return, but it would be nice if that somehow depended one the order of subqueries, e. g. in the last example it would be two rows, and in reversed (`t2 UNION t1`) — one.

I can do it with a huge query, but the question is — is there a standard method for such operation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I don't think there's a built-in operator for this. It's a pretty unusual requirement, I think. What's the use case?

Comment: @Barmar Roughly speaking, I have two tables A and B. Sometimes entries from A are copied to B, sometimes — moved. I need to find out how many entries were there in table A in the beginning. I union distinctly both tables, so similar rows from one table get lost, which is not cool. There's such business logic that either no same rows are copied to B or all at once. So, I need the `union` to return number N in cases if N similar rows haven't been copied yet, or have already been copied, or have already been moved. And of course I am allowed only to select in that project.

Comment: So you want to union table 1 with all the rows in table 2 that don't match anything in table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a union of `table1` with all the rows in `table2` that don't have matching rows in `table1`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 USING (a, b, ...) -- list all the columns here
WHERE t1.a IS NULL
```

Comment: How nice, that's exactly asymmetric `union semi` which I wanted. Thank you.